# Modify previous and next text from pagination links

Tags: php, functions, pagination, html

I set the pagination parameters in functions.php and echoed where I want the links to appear, so far so good.

The problem is that the previous and next texts are not modifying. I put a random text to see what appears. The texts of the images below are shown, they are even translated into my language (pt-br)...

How can i modify them?

[image]

[image]

```
<?php $args = array(
'base'               => '%_%',
'format'             => '?paged=%#%',
'total'              => 1,
'current'            => 0,
'show_all'           => false,
'end_size'           => 1,
'mid_size'           => 2,
'prev_next'          => true,
'prev_text'          => __('jdsjj'),
'next_text'          => __('jhdsh'),
'type'               => 'list',
'add_args'           => false,
'add_fragment'       => '',
'before_page_number' => '',
'after_page_number'  => ''); ?>

<!-- Pagination links echoed in my home page -->
<?php echo paginate_links( $args ); ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out a way that you can place any text. You just need to create an array where you want the paginate_links to appear.

```
<!-- Put this in your functions.php -->
<?php $args = array(
   'base'               => '%_%',
   'format'             => '?paged=%#%',
   'total'              => 1,
   'current'            => 0,
   'show_all'           => false,
   'end_size'           => 1,
   'mid_size'           => 2,
   'add_args'           => false,
   'add_fragment'       => '',
   'before_page_number' => '',
   'after_page_number'  => ''); ?>

<!-- Put this where you want the paginate_links to appear -->
<?php echo paginate_links( array(

  'prev_text' => '<span>Any text Previous</span>',
  'next_text' => '<span>Any text Next</span>'

)); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

are you using WordPress in default `"en"` language? there might be a translations of `prev_text` & `next_text` stored in `"po/mo"` files. & if you are using language other then default then maybe the system is using translated string from `mo` file. 
try removing these two keys and values from array for a while to see what happens.

```
'prev_text'          => __('jdsjj'),
'next_text'          => __('jhdsh'),
```

also after that trial remove `get text` helper function too. and see the result.

```
'prev_text'          => 'jdsjj',
'next_text'          => 'jhdsh',
```

if the problem is because of `"Languages"` then the complete solution is to rewrite all of your `mo` files from up to date `pot`

Comment: I removed and changed the way you showed, but did not change anything. What I want is to be able to change the text to anything. Do you know why the array is not allowing this?

Comment: @Gabriel Souza this may be cause of site language. are you using default english language or any other language then english?

Comment: i'm using portuguese from Brazil

Comment: switch the language to default ( English ) to see if the changes are working? if it does then as i told you before you have to re generate the mo files from up to date pot. which is located in your theme's language directory.

Comment: It did not work. How do I re generate these files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499622/how-can-i-create-an-mo-file-for-wordpress